# Force mongoose.save callback to wait for write to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, synchronous

I think this is simple but I can't seem to get it to work. I have two processes. One that consumes data, and then another that decorates it. They're connected by a queue service. The first one 'saves' the document and then queues the second:

```
// 'post' is a mongoose object

post.save(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        self.decorate('post', post.service, post.id);
    }
});
```

Service two receives the queue message, and then attempts to query the queue. But doesn't find the item. The item DOES get written, and if I rerun the queued message a few seconds later, it finds it correctly.

It looks like the second service is trying to run before the write is complete.

How do I force the Mongoose callback to wait/act synchronously? I've tried adding 'safe: true' to the connection options.

Answer (score 4):

Please consider using the promise in save() method.

```
post.save().then(function (savedPost) {
    self.decorate('post', savedPost.service, savedPost.id);
});
```

Comment: This saved me from async hell. Thank you.

Comment: can you do an empty `.then()` just to wait until the async functions returns?

Comment: @Gobliins I think that will not help in this situation as any code that needs to be executed should be inside the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

It would also be good to handle errors as well. So the following code will serve your purpose.

```
yourModel.save().then(function(savedData){
    // do something with saved data
}).catch(function(err){
    // some error occurred while saving, like any required field missing
    throw new Error(err.message);
});
```

If you simply want to return true/false for save then do something like,

```
someFunction() {
    return yourModel.save().then(function(savedData){
        return true;
    }).catch(function(err){
        return false;
    });
}
```